# What is the role of morphisms $A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

From Steve Awodey's *Category Theory*, p. 37:

> Ring homomorphisms $A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ into the initial ring $\mathbb{Z}$ play an equally important role in algebraic geometry.

My question is thus, for someone who knows a reasonable amount of abstract algebra but zero algebraic geometry, what exactly is the role of such morphisms in algebraic geometry?

Comment: The category of affine schemes is equivalent (and may even be defined as) $\mathbf{CRing}^{op}$. This means that a commutative ring homomorphism $A\to\mathbb Z$ is a global element (i.e. an arrow from a terminal object) of $\mathbf{Aff}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These correspond to scheme maps $\text{Spec}\,\Bbb Z\to\text{Spec}\,A$,
so to points of  $\text{Spec}\,A$ defined over $\Bbb Z$.